# Teamviewer is SLOW in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, teamviewer

Recently installed 16.04 on an older Dell 780 4GB Integrated graphics.
I downloaded Teamviewer but it is extremely slow. Does anyone have a fix or clue as to why?

Comment: Do you have a display closed? If so, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in. Because no scanner is connected. :-)
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: why has no given an answer for this? This is a serious problem. To the point teamviewer is no longer an acceptable piece of software for even personal use.

Comment: still no answers?? I have the same problem, dozen of computers with ubuntu 14 and a couple of Ubuntu 16 machines, they are in the same network, and only the Ubuntu 16 machines are extremely slow in remote connection. All the computers are headless, so must be a problem related to Ubuntu 16 in headless system!