# Using A Ubuntu PC Remotely Over an iMac ~ Can't Get Access to The PC Without Monitor Plugged in First

Tags: xorg, display, mac

Duplicate of this question here...
[Add Fake Display when No Monitor is Plugged In](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in)

But I had major complications this Q and A never addressed

After I implemented the top rated answer by following all the steps of installing the dummy driver and creating the xorg.conf file I could no longer get ANY display from my ubuntu PC. Not remotely and not from a monitor. The factor that screwed the pooch in this case may have been my 1080 ti Nvidia graphics card?

The "display" now is just a black screen over the monitor and nothing I can do, that worked before I installed the driver, can get remote access to the PC from the iMac.

I'm already in the process of wiping the HD and re-installing ubuntu. What went wrong? How else could I have resolved this and is there a way to solve the original problem?

Comment: How are you accessing the PC remotely? Through VNC? RDP? TeamViewer? SSH tunneling?

Comment: I'm using 'Screen Sharing' which just pops up like a newly plugged in disk drive in Finder when the PC is on. It was built in to OS Sierra 10.12.4. It lags. (I had to enable screen sharing on Ubuntu of course to let the iMac access it).I also access the PC through terminal with SSH.   [][][][] It wasn't a disaster since the PC is new but I restored it and I'm accessing it through the iMac again but I'd like to put this monitor away so I don't have to turn it on every time I start the PC.....