# x11vnc Headless on Ubuntu is very slow until monitor connected

Tags: networking, server, vnc, headless

I'm running x11vnc on Ubuntu as a service at startup. It generally works fine, but I want to run it headless. If I start the server with a monitor connected but off, VNC connects and responds quickly, however if I restart the server without a monitor connected (I want to remove the monitor from my desk) then it's painfully slow to use - like 5 fps response, until I connect a monitor again and then it's fine.

Here's the content of my service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Start x11vnc at startup
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -display :0 -geometry 1024x768 -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5900 -shared -o /var/log/x11vnc.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Be really grateful if someone can point out where I've gone wrong with this.
Thanks

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not, and now my server has updated to a latest build of 17.10 which x11vnc doesn't work with at the moment :/

Comment: This may be worth looking as a temporary fix: https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in

Answer (score 9):

1. Disable Composite tweaks
   via Start->Window Manager Tweaks->Compositor-> Disable
2. Disable vsync,
   `xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/vblank_mode -s off`

Reference - https://github.com/LibVNC/x11vnc/issues/102

Comment: Omg, thanks for this.  Using Ubuntu Mate 20.04 the x11vnc server was incredibly slow.  Disabling the compositor sped things up well into the usable range.  (`MATE Tweak -> Windows -> Window Manager -> Marco (no compositor)`)

Comment: To disable the compositor from command line : `xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/use_compositing -s false`

Comment: Is this answer specific to xfce, which is an alternative desktop environment?
But I have several plain vanilla Ubuntu installs with "ubuntu:GNOME" desktop environment and none of the proposed solutions work : there is no xfwm4, no Window Manager Tweaks.  Is there a VNC fix for standard Ubuntu?