# x11vnc suddenly very slow

Tags: 14.04, vnc

I recently finally got through the struggle of connecting to a headless ubuntu box that I set up for running as a web cam/ weatherstation/ processing station that I am connecting to with a windows machine. The idea is that this is going to be an 'always on' machine, that I can pop into from windows over my LAN.

It took a while, but I eventually got it figured out and working, and initially it was working very well.. At some point today, when I connected to the machine, the refresh rate for the VNC client dropped to VERY slow speeds, in both Tiger and TightVNC.
Now whenever I connect to the machine, the refresh rate is disappointingly slow.

I'm start the connection to the Ubuntu box via Putty, then issue the following commands via terminal:

```
x11vnc openssh-server
```

and after the server starts

```
x11vnc -usepw
```

I then log in using either TightVNC or TigerVNC. As I said previously, I was getting *great* connection speeds yesterday and the day before and even last night, but this AM, its slowed down to an unusable speed.

When I connect via Moba using RDP, I still get very good connection speed, but I prefer using TightVNC or TigerVNC so that I can always log into the same session.
Thoughts?
I haven't been able to find a similar issue of speeds dropping with no change in settings.

Comment: Use `wireshark` and/or `tcpdump` to watch the TCP/IP packets go back and forth. You won't see what's in the packets, but packet headers have a lot of info.

Comment: @waltinator So.. some voodoo going on here. A little forensics on my own end. Slow down came after I moved the machine to another location in my office. When I moved it, I had to unplug its monitor (but its supposed to be headless, so this is the point. Plugged back in the monitor and were cooking with grease again. Thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [x11vnc Headless on Ubuntu is very slow until monitor connected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950252/x11vnc-headless-on-ubuntu-is-very-slow-until-monitor-connected)

Comment: See also [Ubuntu 16.04 headless Desktop Sharing with VNC is slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890346/ubuntu-16-04-headless-desktop-sharing-with-vnc-is-slow?noredirect=1&lq=1)