# Ubuntu 16.04- VNC/TeamViewer, setting screen resolution in headless mode

Tags: display-resolution, vnc, teamviewer, headless

Ubuntu 16.04 is installed on an OLD PC, and should be used headless (without display connected). Due to this fact, when trying to use VNC (x11vnc server is installed) or TeamViewer, its resolution is set somehow to 640x480.

How can I get it changed while it is headless?

Comment: @user68186 adding a fake display is obviously one way to do it. This solution did not work for me

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details of what you tried and what results and errors you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer this question properly, but I found a pure software and better solution. [Add Fake Display when No Monitor is Plugged In](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in)

---

Email from RealVNC support team:

> Hi Guy,
>
> If there is no monitor plugged in to the computer, it defaults back to
>   the safest resolution, 640 x 480.
>
> I'd recommend an EDID emulator. This will allow you to set a
>   resolution without the need for a monitor plugged in.
>
> You would need one that supports Linux, however this is an example of
>   one:
>   https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pass-Through-Emulator-splitters-Switches-Extenders-HDMI-EDID/dp/B072JC9443/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1505822141&sr=1-1&keywords=edid
>
> Please note, we cannot recommend any particular brand/vendor.
>
> I hope this helps.
>
> Regards, Simon Product Support Engineer
>
> Ticket Details Ticket ID: TIM-497-72944 Status: On Hold

Asking for a Non Hardware solution:

> Guy,
>
> Yes, there is. My apologies.
>
> There is a parameter in the VNC Server settings when running it in
>   Virtual mode - for this you must have an Enterprise subscription.
>
> https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/server-modes.html#server-modes
>
> https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/server-parameter-ref.html#RandR
>
> You can set your resolution from here.
>
> Regards, Simon Product Support Engineer
>
> Ticket Details Ticket ID: TIM-497-72944 Status: On Hold