# How do I keep display settings when a monitor is turned off

Tags: nvidia, display

I currently have dual screen setup:

[image]

When I turn off one of my monitors, it reverts back to one monitor:

[image]

It's real annoying, because I want to set up a vnc client, and keep the monitors off.

I'm sure it has something to do with my particular monitors, but can I just tell ubuntu to keep these display settings no matter what?

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: The display settings are kept and you can test that simply by reconnecting or turning on the other monitor. What you describe is what typically happens and it's only logical, why would the settings tool report a non-existent monitor? And what does all that have to do with VNC?

Comment: @MichaelBay when I turn off both monitors the VNC client can't connect anymore.  I'm connecting from a different machine that has two monitors, so I want this machine to keep its two displays.  It's not logical for an operating system to throw all my panels on top of each other when a monitor goes missing.  I guess I need virtual monitors instead.  It's just garbage that their doesn't seem to an intuitive way to tell ubuntu to lock the display layout as is.  Am I the first person to turn off my monitors when I leave the office but keep my machine on so I can connect remotely?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in but no, you can't have two dummies.

Comment: @MichaelBay its fine. I'll just use different monitors.