# How can I make VINO to start at the startup?

Tags: startup, vnc, vino

I have VINO installed to control my PC remotely.
But if I reboot my PC (Ubuntu 18.04), the first screen I see is the login screen.

It seems that I necessarily need to log in for Vino to start, because I try to connect to my PC through VNC, the connection fails, but If I make login, after I will be able to connect through VNC successfully.

So, my question is: Is there any way to avoid the necessity of making log in everytime I reboot my PC ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get vino VNC server to start on startup in Ubuntu 18.04.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062727/how-to-get-vino-vnc-server-to-start-on-startup-in-ubuntu-18-04-1)

Comment: You have to be logged in for vino to work, so the only way to get what you want is to set your pc to autologin and set vino to autostart. Or you could use a different screen sharing program that does not require you to log in.