# How can I connect to an ubuntu 19.10 server with gui?

Tags: ssh, windows, gui

I'm trying to connect to my server and view the gui from windows. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: A simple and light-weight method with `ssh -X` (and openssh-server) is described at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398).

Answer (score 0):

You can install and run a VNC server (x11vnc) on your Linux box, and then connect to it from your windows machine using a VNC client..

I dont know if you are asking about vnc/remote desktop/etc, or if you are talking about x11. and doing it all through ssh (cause you just tagged ssh).

Sorry, you weren't too clear.

Either way, look up SSH X11, and VNC..

One of those two should be what you are looking for.

Cheers!
-Booey

Answer (score 0):

In case your Ubuntu 19.10 server does not have a monitor attached to it you might have to create a "dummy display". This may help you in achieving that: [Headless server: no monitor, no graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066721/headless-server-no-monitor-no-graphics)