# Access Ubuntu device from Windows 10

Tags: display, remote-desktop, remote-access

I am trying to set up remote access to my Ubuntu device (Ubuntu 18.04.2 desktop) from Windows 10.

I tried xRDP but could only get a pale blue screen appearing. Also the device is set to auto-login so I don't think xRDP will work as I read there are issues if there is an existing login session.

Looking for something simpler, I tried TeamViewer and NoMachine and both worked fine until I disconnected the monitor from the device and put it in the cabinet where I intend to store and run it from. For both applications, I get a black screen.

NoMachine has an article about configuring its own X server which I followed but no change. In another article, I found like TeamViewer it considers headless/monitorless unsupported.

I've now found references to setting up a virtual display as outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1062887/960140). However after copying pasting the text into the `20-intel.conf` file, it's still not visible in the list of displays if I run `xrandr`. As shown below:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00    50.00  
   720x576i      50.00    50.00  
   720x480       60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Could someone please provide some advice/pointers on how to proceed at this point and if there is an easier to implement a solution?

Comment: Do you want to see/control the single desktop or do you want a separate session for the remote machine?