# VNC doesn't work with display switched off

Tags: gnome, vnc, headless

I have my Ubuntu 19.10 HTPC plugged-in to a HDMI switch, which then routes to my monitor. Most of the time that HDMI switch is set to my Nvidia ShieldTV streaming device, and the TV is off.

When I VNC into my HTPC, I am often unable to do *anything* on the screen. Mouse and keyboard inputs through VNC are completely ignored. Looking through syslog, I found a "monitor is undefined" error.

```
Oct 21 15:37:30 myhost gnome-shell[1119]: JS ERROR: Extension dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com: TypeError: monitor is undefined#012checkIfFocusedMonitor@/home/myuser/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/panelManager.js:266:9#012_adjustForOverview@/home/myuser/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/panel.js:429:32#012enable@/home/myuser/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/panel.js:112:9#012enable@/home/myuser/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/panelManager.js:72:9#012_enable@/home/myuser/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/extension.js:91:5#012enable@/home/myuser/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/extension.js:63:5#012_callExtensionEnable@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:132:13#012loadExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:264:21#012_loadExtensions/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:482:13#012collectFromDatadirs@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/fileUtils.js:27:17#012_loadExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:457:9#012_enableAllExtensions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:491:13#012_sessionUpdated@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:522:13#012init@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:32:9#012_initializeUI@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:245:5#012start@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:141:5#012@<main>:1:31
```

Sure enough, when I turned the TV on everything immediately starts to work after a systemctl restart gdm (which did not work previously).

From my research, I found this question below which addresses running Ubuntu headless.

[How to use Ubuntu 18.04 on VNC without display attached?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033436/how-to-use-ubuntu-18-04-on-vnc-without-display-attached)

However I am *not* running headless, I have a monitor attached, it's just turned off. Any way to make this work at the X/Gnome level?

Additionally I tried disabling all Gnome extensions entirely in the tweak tool and the problem still happened. So this is not an extension problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered the same issue:
Ubuntu 18.04 with x11vnc. Turn off monitor and VNC client at the other side freezes, turn on again and it works fine.

Fix/Workaround: replace the HDMI to HDMI cable from pc to monitor with a DVI to DVI cable from pc to monitor. Now turning off and on the monitor does not influence the VNC client anymore.

Do not ask why, it just works now.