# Ubuntu 18.04 VNC/Vino stops refreshing when turning display off

Tags: 18.04, xorg, screen, vnc, display-manager

After upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 I'm having trouble with VNC/Vino.

I can connect via VNC (by enabling the built-in 'Screen Sharing' option), but as soon as I turn of the local display (server is connected to a TV, not a regular monitor), the VNC connection stops working for anything but the active windows. In other words: the background and the dock are not refreshed and the connection becomes very difficult to use (see screenshot).

Anyone has any idea where to look for a solution? I saw some posts about adding a dummy monitor, but that does not seem to apply to my case.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I just want to add this piece of information: now it seems that it also creates a 'second virtual monitor', so my setup after loging in with Remmina is now a 'multi-screen'  setup. However, I'm stuck at one of the screens and unable to switch to the screen where new windows open.

This is all very confusing.. I'm repenting upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 :(..

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: I see the same artifacts. Also the Ubuntu dock seems to stop working via VNC as soon as I turn off the monitor on the host machine. As soon as I turn the monitor on again (pressing the physcal button on the monitor), the dock works again via VNC.

Comment: @Warner if it were me reinstalling would be the solution. obviously the upgrade is the culprit here. at least confirm what I'm saying by booting to a liveusb. also I don't know why you tagged this as xorg. 18.04 runs on wayland not xorg.

Comment: I guess reinstalling is the only option I have left.. Not too happy about it especially since I have webservers configured on the machine :(

Comment: So I reinstalled to a fresh copy of 18.04 and I'm having exactly the same problem!

One additional piece of information: I'm having a television connected to this machine, not a regular monitor. It seems that when the TV is off, Ubuntu (or Wayland) mistakenly thinks there is no monitor connected any longer. 

Any help would be very welcome!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on Intel NUC with Ubuntu 19.04 and solved it by disabling of KMS for Intel graphics:

- Set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset i915.modeset=0"` in /etc/default/grub
- Run `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
- Reboot

Related issue I solved later: If you reboot your machine when display is disconnected, X server might not start. Then:

- Use config from https://techoverflow.net/2019/02/23/how-to-run-x-server-using-xserver-xorg-video-dummy-driver-on-ubuntu/
- And install "xserver-xorg-video-dummy-hwe-18.04" and configure according to [Add Fake Display when No Monitor is Plugged In](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. This does indeed solve part of the issue, but it also creates a new one: when I try "nomodeset", it only recognizes a default display (1024*768) after boot. 
Any clues on how to solve this part?