# Adding a fake monitor for headless system breaks boot when a real monitor is connected

Tags: 16.04, display, headless

I'm trying to add a fake monitor in Ubuntu 16.04. This is a headless system and the problem is that remote desktop like teamviewer are really slow, so I tried the accepted solution here:

[Add Fake Display when No Monitor is Plugged In](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in/463000#463000)

Now is properly working when is headless, but as soon I connect a real monitor, it doesn't work anymore (get stuck at boot), unless I delete xorg.conf file (as suggested in the comments in the link provided).

Any other solution?

Hardware dummy plug is not an option.

Comment: An alternate to adding a fake monitor, in that manner, you could try loading X drivers without looking for a monitor, something along the lines of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085161/ubunut-16-04-starup-gui-application-without-display/1085165?noredirect=1#comment1785124_1085165 I am not sure if it will help your case though.