# How can I start a Qt GUI application on boot without a display connected?

Tags: 16.04, xorg, startup, services

I need to run a Qt GUI App on every system start and run it forever. I have created a system service for it.

Here is the service file content:

`QtGUIAPP.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=QtGUIAPP

[Service]
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/user/.Xauthority"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /home/user/QtGUIAPP --no-sandbox
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The above works fine without any problem.

But when I boot the PC without a monitor and access it remotely, the application seems not to be running. And I get an error in syslog like

```
 Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyQStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0Could not connect to any X display.
Oct 18 12:45:55 user systemd[1]: QtGUIAPP.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 18 12:45:55 user systemd[1]: QtGUIAPP.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 18 12:45:55 user systemd[1]: QtGUIAPP.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 18 12:45:55 user avahi-daemon[799]: Host name conflict, retrying with user-2
Oct 18 12:45:55 user avahi-daemon[799]: Registering new address record for 10.0.7.15 on enp2s0.IPv4.
Oct 18 12:45:56 user systemd[1]: QtGUIAPP.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
```

I think the problem is with the line

```
 Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
```

How can I change the above script to make it work both when a display is connected and not connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can run Qt without X, so you need to run X. It won't start by default if a monitor is not detected.

I found [this Ubuntu Forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1466271) ([link to exact answer](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1466271&page=2&p=9759320#post9759320)) that might help you get over the problem of not being able to connect a monitor:

I am not that great with Ubuntu (been using it for past 2 years), so there might be other options to do the same.

> I was having the exact same problem - I want to run X on a machine that (for now) doesn't have a monitor attached.
>
> Using the intel driver, X was finding no monitors attached, and giving up:
>
> ```
> (II) intel(0): Output VGA disconnected
> (WW) intel(0): No outputs definitely connected, trying again...
> (II) intel(0): Output VGA disconnected
> (WW) intel(0): Unable to find initial modes
> (EE) intel(0): No valid modes.
> (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
> ```
>
> I stumbled across a solution pieced together from several different threads on these and other forums.
>
> First I needed to make a basic `xorg.conf` file, in which I specified the VESA driver rather than the intel one (see bottom of post for my `xorg.conf`)
>
> This led to me seeing a different error:
>
> ```
> (EE) VESA: Kernel modesetting driver in use, refusing to load
> (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
> (EE) No devices detected.
> ```
>
> I then had to add `nomodeset` to my GRUB boot options (used to be in `/boot/grub/menu.lst` but now in `/etc/default/grub`)
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
> ```
>
> ...and run `sudo update-grub`.
>
> With some basic settings for the (non-existent) monitor, the result is that I get X running with no monitor plugged in, using the VESA driver, and with a decent resolution - which is fine for what I wanted it for.
>
> The `xorg.conf` file:
>
> ```
> Section "Monitor"
>   Identifier   "Monitor0"
>   HorizSync    31-81
>   VertRefresh  56-75
> EndSection
>
> Section "Device"
>   Identifier  "Card0"
>   Driver      "vesa"
> EndSection
>
> Section "Screen"
>     Identifier "Screen0"
>     Device     "Card0"
>     Monitor    "Monitor0"
> EndSection
> ```

Comment: What's the answer? This is just a link, and they're known to disappear

Comment: Sorry, I did not want to copy the answer as mine so I linked the post. The second page of the forum mentions a working method posted by  mr_git. If you really care about the link disappearing, you can by all means copy the answer and paste it here.

Comment: Really should copy the main answer, it's not plagiarism as long as it's attributed to the source with the link, otherwise your answer here doesn't really answer anything ;-)