# Running headless doesn't start correctly unless a display is attached

Tags: headless

I want to run Ubuntu 18 headless and connect with AnyDesk.  Everything works fine as long as there is a display connected, even when not powered on. If I don't have a display attached, then when it starts up, AnyDesk connects but with a black screen.  When I then attach a monitor to look at it, it's started, but looks like it's on the activity screen.

Even unplugging it after boot and being connected with AnyDesk causes things to screw up.  But if I plug the display back in, everything works again.

I tried changed the resolution, but that didn't seem to help.

I'm a Linux newbie, so I'm not sure where to look for log files or something that would tell me what's going on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Can you post the output of this command? -->> ps aux | grep "dm"

Comment: Is the system reachable over network when running headless? (`ping` or `ssh`)

Comment: I am running ubuntu 20.4 and Anydesk 6.2.1 on a Lenovo ThinkCentre M720q and I have the same issue. Anydesk only works correctly when connected to an external monitor. If the monitor is disconnected, the anydesk app returns an intermittent image and sometimes crashes the interface or the machine. It can break ssh connections and not be able to reconnect. I have not seen this issue with mac or windows anydesk connections.

Answer (score 4):

I use NoMachine with a headless server without a monitor on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS 64 bit an it runs fine. I have also tested NoMachine on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS 64 bit, but it was not a headless machine. I am not familiar with AnyDesk, but NoMachine should work fine with a headless Ubuntu 18.04 machine. VNC also works great for a headless environment but NoMachine is easier to use. For NoMachine to work, it needs to be installed on the server and the client. It is cross-platform and also provides a mobile app. Here is a link to download NoMahine: https://www.nomachine.com/

Edit: As of now, NoMachine does not work on headless machines anymore, but I found a solution when I installed a video dummy driver that emulates a fake monitor and works great. Here is the link to the solution: [Add Fake Display when No Monitor is Plugged In](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in).

Answer (score 0):

After a little investigation, this seems to be a common issue for desktop PCs that need an attached monitor to work. There are system hacks, but they are dangerous.

I solved this with an HDMI Ghost Display Emulator. It is a dongle that plugs in the place of an HDMI cable and makes the PC think that there is an attached monitor.