# Screen sharing only working when monitor connected

Tags: vino

Using Ubuntu 19.04, I can only use the built-in screen sharing (vino) when a monitor is connected. I can successfully connect even without a monitor connected, but the screen isn't updated (ie I see the screen as it was the moment I disconnected the monitor.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Isn't vino just a screen sharing program? If you want remote access without a monitor being attached don't you need a different program like SSH (secure Shell)

Comment: I have ssh working, I'd like screen sharing as well

Comment: Wil this link help - adding a fake display? https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in

Comment: Nope, it breaks X completely. Also it's not exactly the same issue - I actually can connect to vino, the screen just isn't updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't feel like the most elegant solution but this issue was solved for me by one of those HDMI dummy plugs which emulates a connected screen. They can be picked up for about $10.

I've found the wide range of resolutions they spoof to be handy.