# 19.10 Keyboard and mouse and monitor required to use Desktop Sharing?

Tags: 19.10, vnc, vino

In the past I've used tightvnc and tigervnc. I decided to try and use the built in desktop sharing feature of Ubuntu 19.10. It works great as long as the mouse and keyboard are plugged in. When they are plugged in I am able to control the desktop remotely (used my phone successfully several times). The thing is that when I unplug the keyboard, mouse and monitor from the server and plug them back into my workstation I can only view the screen and cannot control it. The screen seems frozen from when I last used it. If I plug the peripherals back in I can control it with my phone with no issue. Unplug it and I'm frozen and it shows a frozen screen of the desktop (not even the password prompt). I have tried hitting ESC and other keys to see if it brings me to the password prompt but it didn't work. Is there an option that needs to be set that I'm missing?

Comment: Weird. I use vino on 18.04 to control a server that just's a box, no screen, mouse, or keyboard. Hope this isn't a functional regression in 19.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be the screen that's key rather than the keyboard and mouse?

I was having the same issue without a screen attached. Unfortunately the only solution that worked for me was a dummy HDMI connector that emulated a screen.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1233892/1057813

Comment: This is correct. It has to have a screen attached. I had trouble with a virtual screen but either plugging it in to a monitor or getting a dummy plug worked. It wasn't the keyboard or mouse.