# VNC on Ubuntu 20.04 without monitor

Tags: gnome, 20.04, remote-desktop, vnc

since couple of days I am trying to set VNC Connection with my "server" Ubuntu desktop 20.04. I want to use it as remote workstation and I want to use gnome3 environment, VNC Connect or NoMachine (for better management). Everything works well as long as monitor is attached. As soon as I remove monitor - connection breaks. Ok, that's how it works. I have created dummy screen...

> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-dummy

With config based on this post:

> [Add Fake Display when No Monitor is Plugged In](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in)

I can access server, but it stuck on login screen with password prompt. When I put password, nothing happen. Still login screen with password prompt.

If anybody have any idea - please, help.

Regards

Comment: I'd buy Dummy VGA Plug/Adaptor only cost me $1.99 in my country, no hassle with `xorg` setting.

Comment: Yup, I didn't realize that they exist. For test purpose I will do it myself tomorrow (have a lot of electronic trash). Otherwise I would need to wait for package for next couple of days...

Answer (score 0):

Dummy VGA to HDMI solved the problem.

Description here:

> https://www.geeks3d.com/20091230/vga-hack-how-to-make-a-vga-dummy-plug/

[image: This one I have made]