# Fake Display with no dummy adapter

Tags: drivers, server, 20.04

Is there a program that emulates a display with variable resulution?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean by "emulate a display" and why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: @danzel like a driver, for anydesk there needs to be an active display plugged in, somethings that adds a virtual displayoutput where you can customize the resulotion

Comment: Your question seems to be lacking some important information. Please [edit] your question and tell us what your actual problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Fake Display when No Monitor is Plugged In](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/453109/26246 Has some other options for dynamic resolution, probably only with Xorg.