# How do I increase the resolution of headless system using dummy monitor?

Tags: display-resolution, monitor, headless

Please, this question has not been answered, I have read them all and none seems to work for me.

I have a headless system Ubuntu 20.04 with Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8570D]

and I have installed the

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-dummy
```

with changes to the `xorg.conf`

I am stuck with max resolution of 1360x768

Any ideas how to get higher resolution?

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in/713768#comment1555075_713768

Comment: This might help the discussion.  The link suggests the solution:   

$xrandr --fb 1600x900    

It gives me the following:

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 1360x768 (desired size 1600x900)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/HmqnyEud

Answer (score 0):

after installing **xserver-xorg-video-dummy** with the command

`sudo apt install -y xserver-xorg-video-dummy`

paste the high res configuration into the file **20-dummy.conf**

`sudo cat > /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-dummy.conf`

following content:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "DummyDevice"
    Driver "dummy"
    VideoRam 1024000
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "DummyScreen"
    Device "DummyDevice"
    Monitor "DummyMonitor"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 24
        Modes "2560x1440_60.0"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DummyMonitor"
    HorizSync 30-200
    VertRefresh 50-1000
    Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
EndSection
```

if you need another resolution, call the **calculate VESA CVT mode lines**:

`cvt 2048 1440`

then copy over cvt 2048 1440 generated string into the **20-dummy.conf** file

```
# 2048x1440 59.97 Hz (CVT) hsync: 89.53 kHz; pclk: 249.25 MHz
Modeline "2048x1440_60.00"  249.25  2048 2200 2416 2784  1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

update the same resolution mode name **"2048x1440_60.00"** in the **SubSection "Display"**

and reboot