# Startxfce without a screen?

Tags: server, ssh, xfce, remote-desktop, rdp

I'm connecting to my Ubuntu 18 server through RDP (xRDP) with xfce as environment.
Some scripts are launched when the graphic interface is launched. (these scripts required the graphic interface).

After a reboot of the server; I need to connect through RDP to launch the graphic interface (and so the scripts), I would like the server to launch automatically the desktop interface.

I tried to create a dummy monitor without success; startxfce from ssh still can't find the screen.
I also tried to use rdpy but it seems it's not working with xRDP

Best regards.

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist snap based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances, devices & cloud use do use a *yy* format, but none are titled just Ubuntu 18.  Please clarify your release as there is no Ubuntu 18.  Releases using the *yy* format are *snap* only, run in containerized environments thus are somewhat different.

Comment: This is possible by using Xvnc that creates you a virtual desktop which will even work on headless nodes.    https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313445/how-do-i-install-vnc-on-a-headless-ubuntu-20-10