# 22.04 - Remote Desktop Sharing password changes in every reboot

Tags: password, remote, sharing

VNC Password got changed every boot.

- not to change password, as required work after system reboot.
- auto logging is on.

[image]

Also how to start the VNC service default when not logged in to the desktop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.04 remote desktop headless?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407444/ubuntu-22-04-remote-desktop-headless)

Comment: no.. we need some more informaiton as ask in issue details

Comment: Either disable auto login. Or disable Remote Desktop from settings, and install a vnc server. Try something like [How do I install vnc on a headless ubuntu 20.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313445/how-do-i-install-vnc-on-a-headless-ubuntu-20-10)

Comment: Auto loging is disable (able to disable the auto update vnc password)
Now, how to start vnc-server after every reboot the host (desktop), without loging.

Comment: Auto loging is disable (able to disable the auto update vnc password)Now, how to start vnc-server after every reboot the host (desktop), without loging.

Comment: You cannot use the **Gnome Remote Desktop** sharing without logging in locally first. One solution is to install `xrdp` (and use RDP protocol), without using the built in **Gnome Remote Desktop**. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407444/ubuntu-22-04-remote-desktop-headless/1409120#1409120) for details.