# How can I create virtual display on AMD GPU

Tags: drivers, radeon, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I want to create a virtual display on the xorg. (I already has one display. I wants another one.)

I am using a AMD GPU, lspci output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 / Radeon 520 OEM] (rev 87) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 / Radeon 520 OEM]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 130
Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at dfe00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: radeon
Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

Note:
I tried adding `options amdgpu virtual_display=0000:01:00.0,2` in modprode configuration, but it doesn't work.

Comment: [Here you go](https://askubuntu.com/a/463000/1091774). This answer will tell you exactly how to do it via software.

Comment: @Matigo does not work & broke my os. Login to see black screen.

Comment: I have bad [news](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi%3Fid%3D203339&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjO_auPgez6AhVtiYsKHUw_BVcQFnoECAoQAg&usg=AOvVaw2lMbbU6dprvyuFyRlDYVp0) for you. It's impossible.