# Anydesk showing black screen until Ubuntu user is logged in

Tags: anydesk

I am unable to find a resolution to this, can someone advise

I have anydesk running on my windows PC and remote Ubuntu machine.

When remote Ubuntu machine boots up, my any desk screen will only show black screen. It will keep showing black screen until the user has logged in to the Ubuntu OS.

Anydesk is added into the startup applications in the remote machine.

looking at some other posts i also enabled the wayland. But still unable to resolve this.

I want to get to a situation where remote user does not have to login to the Ubuntu OS, and i can still Anydesk using unattended access.

Comment: I doubt you will be able to do this. Anydesk is an application not a service. To have it start before login would require it to be a service. You could ask the Anydesk people if this is possible.

Comment: Seems like the a different issue. So, Anydesk is actually working at the device boot up before logging in to the user profile. Issue seems to be that when I have display monitor connected to the remote device then i do not get black screen but when there is no monitor connected then i am getting black screen

Comment: I have also changed the settings on the screen lock to not blank or screen lock on any conditions but nothing helped

Comment: Issue is resolved- I used HDMI dummy plug,Headless Ghost, Display Emulator （Fit Headless-1920x1080 New generation@60Hz）and after that without connecting the monitor I was able to get the login screen all ok.

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to add my two cents. I was able to get Anydesk and ScreenConnect to work by creating a virtual dummy monitor as described here:

[Add Fake Display when No Monitor is Plugged In](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in/463000#463000?newreg=cfb099bbd44e4949b87f07d1a53db497)

Found a way to do it without requiring a dummy plug: Ubuntu Headless VNC VESA 800x600 Resolution Fix ~ Andy Hawkins @ June 12, 2011

Basically install a dummy driver:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-dummy
```

Then write it in the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf` (or possibly `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`) file (create one, if it does not exist):

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "dummy"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync 31.5-48.5
    VertRefresh 50-70
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1024x800"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Then restart the computer.

Comment: Thx. Always good to see a software solution that can be implemented immediately instead of having to go out & buy / wait for the delivery of hardware.

Answer (score 1):

AliBhatti's comment is inline with the [answer posted by AnyDesk support](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnyDesk/comments/esd3m1/anydesk_in_linux_gives_black_screen/fgors7d) in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnyDesk/comments/esd3m1/anydesk_in_linux_gives_black_screen/).

@AnyDeskSupport: *... currently AnyDesk might need an active display signal to function properly. As a workaround you can use a headless adapter, to emulate a visual signal*.

Edit: Since initially posting this reply, I have confirmed that using a HDMI dummy plug solved my issue.