# Benchmarking a GPU on a node with no display or monitor

Tags: nvidia, graphics, gpu, benchmarks

How can I benchmark a GPU on a machine that has no display connected to it?

---

I am provisioning VMs with different types of GPUs. I want to benchmark the GPUs in order to compare them. But they're (remote) VMs. There's no display.

I tried for example running `glxgears` in tty, but it says there's no display.

Note that these are the currently available GPUs that I can provision. They're Nvidia.

```
"NVIDIA Corporation TU102GL [Quadro RTX 6000/8000] (rev a1)"
"NVIDIA Corporation TU104GL [Tesla T4] (rev a1)"
```

---

[This reference](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-gpu-benchmark/) has some ways to benchmark a GPU, but they require a display.

- ```
  sudo apt install mesa-utils
  glxgears
  ```
- ```
  sudo apt-get install glmark2
  glmark2
  ```

Comment: Have you found a solution so far?

Comment: Haven't found any ideas unfortunately, no, but haven't been searching.

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup a virtual display.
You can do this by following this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1111898/1737085

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1321439)