# Use xrandr to create a virtual screen for remote connections

Tags: networking, ssh, xorg, vnc

I have a remote, headless and unattended machine that runs Ubuntu 20.04 Server.
I also installed `gdm3` in order to have a remote desktop to simplify some operations.

To remotely access the desktop I use [Zoho Assist](https://www.zoho.com/it/assist/) but as far as I understand the problem I'm experience is for *any* VNC connection.

It happens that when I run the PC with monitor attached I can see the desktop. Instead, in the operative conditions (without the screen) I can make the connection but the screen appears black.

So I'm trying to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/713768/1036006) approach:

```
xrandr --fb 1280x1024
```

From the Zoho Assist command prompt (that is more similar to a keyboard connected to the machine rather than an SSH connection) I get this:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY 
$ :0
$ xrandr --fb 1280x1024 --display :0
$
```

But nothing happens. I still see the black screen if I try to connect.
Please not I configured `gdm3` to boot with X11 - not Wayland.