# Stop Ubuntu from detecting when display is disconnected

Tags: 20.04

I am setting up a simple Ubuntu machine on a KVM switch. One of the monitors is on this switch and the other is not. I want the KVM switch to always be the primary display, even when it is connected to my other computer (appears as completely disconnected to Ubuntu). Ideally I would like for it to just stop detecting changes to the monitor configuration. I have found some commands with xrandr that should solve my issue but none of them seem to work with Ubuntu 20.04 (for example:`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr active false` and others with different schemas). Let me know if I was even close with xrandr or if there is a better solution I could learn about.

Comment: xrandr commands may work with xorg but not with wayland.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is at a lower level.

What is your GPU? I suspect it's an AMD GPU.

If that's the case you can fix it by disabling `amdgpu.dc` at boot time which will prevent the GPU from knowing when your "monitor" is turned off.

However this fix won't work for newer cards (e.g. RDNA2) since they *need* DC to be on.

The ticket tracking this bug is in https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/461

Another possible workaround is to use the HDMI port, since this issue mostly pertains to DisplayPort ports (AFAIK).

Comment: It is using integrated intel graphics. And I am not sure it is a bug, I think that my KVM switch is cheap and gives no indication that there is a connection when the source is not in use. It looks to the computer as if the cable is completely disconnected. (and this is on hdmi already)

Comment: Ok then, something that may work is to create a fake monitor and have both displays (real + fake) set to mirror: https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in so that when your KVM switches, your fake display is still plugged keeping your desktop settings alive

Comment: That is exactly the type of solution I am looking for, thank you! I will give that a try when I get a minute.

Comment: The solution linked completely disabled my real displays. I had to boot into recovery mode and undo the change. People have commented under it that it completely bricked their system. Be careful

Comment: Ouch!!! mmm I suspect it may have been bricked because writing your own xorg.conf can be very hard (as you need to setup EVERYTHING). A better option is to add a file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` to setup your extra monitors. If the system fails, check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to see what went wrong. But first install SSH server so you can control it comfy from a laptop or 2nd computer and use `sshfs username@192.168.1.x:/ /mnt -o default_permissions,idmap=user` to access your server files from there