# Let Android Phone Act as a Monitor for Ubuntu

Tags: display, android

I am using an Android phone and I have wired it to my Ubuntu laptop with USB. I have `scrcpy` installed, which mirrors **Android** to **Ubuntu**, but I'd like a program that does the opposite: mirror **Ubuntu** to **Android** so that the Android phone acts as a monitor or secondary display to Ubuntu.

Comment: You could use almost any VNC viewer application on the phone while serving the entire Ubuntu display on your local network. This would be a _duplicate_ of whatever the existing display presents and that may not be what you are looking for. [fairly painless setup for 18.04](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-and-configure-tigervnc-server-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1318366/1114729 See FantomX1's comment for _non-duplicate_ screen idea.