# Updated to 22.04 LTS → Boot now stuck on '[...] HDMI/DP requires binding with gfx driver

Tags: boot, 22.04

After updating from Ubuntu 20.04 → 22.04 LTS I am unable to boot. Upon boot the following text keeps blinking:

```
/div/sda5: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks
[64.xx] snd_hda_intel 0000:00"03.0: HSW/BDW HD-audio HDMI/DP requires binding with gfx driver
```

Hardware: Gigabyte BRIX (Intel HD Graphics 5500).

Is anyone familiar with this issue? I am able to login using SSH.

EDIT: I found out what may have caused the issue. Because I use Ubuntu without a monitor I used the information in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/463000/1643632) post to setup a dummy display. However before the update I reverted these changes (i.e. by removing `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`) because with the dummy display enabled, regular displays do not work. After re-enabling the dummy display I can now see the Ubuntu again (over TeamViewer). However, still no output on physical displays. Does anybody have an idea how I can properly disable the dummy display so that I can access Ubuntu through a physical monitor again?

Comment: A Ubuntu Core 20 system should be upgraded to Ubuntu Core 22 and not 22.04 LTS.  The Ubuntu products using the *year* (20) format are specialist products and differ to the far more widely used *year.month* (20.04) products.  The upgrade of 20 to 22 involves no user package changes, where with 20.04 to 22.04 all packages get upgraded; ie. they are different systems.

Comment: Hi @guiverc, I actually upgraded from 20.04 → 22.04 but made a mistake in my initial post. It has been edited.