# Set Monitor Dongle Resolution via RDP on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: display, display-resolution

TLDR; How can I get a headless machine to keep the resolution of a 4K monitor dongle to 1920 x 1080?

Machine running Ubuntu Desktop 22.10. Trying to set this up as headless. Initial configuration of the Ubuntu machine is done with a 1920 x 1080 (HD) monitor connected to it. I can RDP into it using MS Remote Desktop. All great.

The monitor dongle I have is a 4K version. When I unplug the HD monitor and plug in the dongle, the display reverts to the 4K resolution of the dongle. I can, via RDP select a resolution of 1920 x 1080 but as soon as I click "Apply", MS Remote drops the connection, and I cannot confirm by clicking the "Keep this resolution" in that dialog box so the display setting resets to 4K.

I can connect both the real display and the dongle and set the dongle resolution to 1920 x 1080, but, as soon as I unplug the real monitor, the system resets the displays and defaults to the 4K resolution of the dongle. Yes, I set the dongle as the main display first.

So, how can I get the machine to keep the resolution of the dongle at 1920 x 1080?

Comment: Yes, I dropped the trailing zero. 22.10 it is.

Comment: Is the Ubuntu running Wayland or Xorg as the display manager? The default is Wayland. You may try switching to Xorg.

Comment: Worth a shot, though the problem seems to be with MS Remote Desktop. As soon as it sees the rest;ution change from what it started the session with, it shuts down the connection.

Comment: Any chance there is a way from the command line in Ubuntu to set the display resolution?

Comment: Many years ago [the accepted solution to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in) worked for me. The problem is, if you connect a real monitor it does not work. I didn't need this for a long time. there may be other better solutions out there.